# Compressing an MTS file to MP4 gives error in QuickTime

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, h.264

I have a long video file that I want to trim, resize, and compress with H264:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 1.2 -to 2:03.800 -i long.MTS -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=320:-1 -vb 500k short.mp4
```

The file plays in VLC and not in QuickTime with this error:

```
The document could not be opened. An unknown error occurred (-50).
```

The same thing happens with the `.mov` container. The problem is that basic users are unable to see the compressed movie, and the original movie is too heavy to share.

The version of `ffmpeg` is 4.3.1, the version of macOS is 10.14.6, both up to date. `ffprobe` on the `.mov` file returns:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'short.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:02:02.92, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 902 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 320x180 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 501 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 394 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

How can I compress, scale, and trim a video from MTS?

**Update**: Here is the new command and the log:

```
$ ffmpeg -y -ac 2 -ss 1.5 -to 2:07.500 -i /Volumes/NO\ NAME/PRIVATE/AVCHD/BDMV/STREAM/00147.MTS -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=540:-1 -vb 500k ~/Downloads/message.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mpegts, from '/Volumes/NO NAME/PRIVATE/AVCHD/BDMV/STREAM/00147.MTS':
  Duration: 00:02:10.11, start: 0.374400, bitrate: 5368 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Stream #0:0[0x1011]: Video: h264 (High) (HDMV / 0x564D4448), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1100]: Audio: ac3 (AC-3 / 0x332D4341), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x1200]: Subtitle: hdmv_pgs_subtitle ([144][0][0][0] / 0x0090), 1920x1080
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (ac3 (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[aac @ 0x7f81d7000800] Using a PCE to encode channel layout "5.1(side)"
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] using SAR=1216/1215
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] profile High, level 2.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] 264 - core 160 r3011 cde9a93 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to '/Users/mmorin/Downloads/message.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 540x304 [SAR 1216:1215 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 500 kb/s, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/500000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 394 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 aac

frame=   30 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.81 bitrate=   0.5kbits/s
frame=   62 fps= 61 q=25.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.09 bitrate=   0.2kbits/
frame=   91 fps= 60 q=24.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:03.30 bitrate=   0.1kbits/
frame=  117 fps= 58 q=23.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:04.30 bitrate= 486.7kbits/
frame=  145 fps= 57 q=22.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:05.39 bitrate= 388.6kbits/
frame=  170 fps= 56 q=23.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:06.42 bitrate= 653.2kbits/
frame=  197 fps= 56 q=23.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:07.53 bitrate= 557.0kbits/
frame=  223 fps= 55 q=23.0 size=     512kB time=00:00:08.59 bitrate= 487.9kbits/
frame=  251 fps= 55 q=22.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:09.64 bitrate= 652.5kbits/
frame=  276 fps= 55 q=23.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:10.64 bitrate= 591.0kbits/
frame=  304 fps= 55 q=22.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:11.79 bitrate= 711.1kbits/
frame=  330 fps= 55 q=23.0 size=    1024kB time=00:00:12.82 bitrate= 654.3kbits/
frame=  352 fps= 54 q=23.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:13.67 bitrate= 766.8kbits/
frame=  379 fps= 54 q=23.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:14.82 bitrate= 707.2kbits/
frame=  403 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:15.72 bitrate= 666.9kbits/
frame=  430 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:16.81 bitrate= 748.5kbits/
frame=  451 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    1536kB time=00:00:17.64 bitrate= 713.2kbits/
frame=  473 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:18.53 bitrate= 791.9kbits/
frame=  499 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:19.62 bitrate= 748.0kbits/
frame=  527 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:20.69 bitrate= 810.8kbits/
frame=  556 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:21.84 bitrate= 768.0kbits/
frame=  583 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:22.93 bitrate= 823.0kbits/
frame=  612 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:24.08 bitrate= 783.7kbits/
frame=  640 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    2304kB time=00:00:25.19 bitrate= 749.2kbits/
frame=  667 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:26.28 bitrate= 797.9kbits/
frame=  691 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:27.30 bitrate= 768.0kbits/
frame=  719 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:28.37 bitrate= 813.1kbits/
frame=  739 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=    2816kB time=00:00:29.22 bitrate= 789.3kbits/
frame=  765 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:30.25 bitrate= 831.9kbits/
frame=  794 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:31.38 bitrate= 801.9kbits/
frame=  823 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:32.59 bitrate= 836.4kbits/
frame=  850 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:33.64 bitrate= 810.4kbits/
frame=  872 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    3328kB time=00:00:34.51 bitrate= 789.8kbits/
frame=  887 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:35.09 bitrate= 836.6kbits/
frame=  910 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:36.01 bitrate= 815.3kbits/
frame=  936 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:37.03 bitrate= 849.4kbits/
frame=  965 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    3840kB time=00:00:38.18 bitrate= 823.8kbits/
frame=  994 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:39.38 bitrate= 852.0kbits/
frame= 1024 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:40.55 bitrate= 827.4kbits/
frame= 1041 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:41.23 bitrate= 813.7kbits/
frame= 1063 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    4352kB time=00:00:42.15 bitrate= 845.7kbits/
frame= 1092 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    4352kB time=00:00:43.28 bitrate= 823.7kbits/
frame= 1118 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:44.33 bitrate= 851.5kbits/
frame= 1143 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:45.33 bitrate= 832.7kbits/
frame= 1165 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    4608kB time=00:00:46.18 bitrate= 817.3kbits/
frame= 1192 fps= 51 q=23.0 size=    4864kB time=00:00:47.27 bitrate= 842.9kbits/
frame= 1221 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    4864kB time=00:00:48.46 bitrate= 822.1kbits/
frame= 1248 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    5120kB time=00:00:49.51 bitrate= 847.1kbits/
frame= 1274 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    5120kB time=00:00:50.58 bitrate= 829.2kbits/
frame= 1303 fps= 51 q=22.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:51.73 bitrate= 851.3kbits/
frame= 1330 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:52.82 bitrate= 833.8kbits/
frame= 1357 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    5632kB time=00:00:53.93 bitrate= 855.5kbits/
frame= 1386 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    5632kB time=00:00:55.06 bitrate= 837.9kbits/
frame= 1416 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    5888kB time=00:00:56.23 bitrate= 857.7kbits/
frame= 1446 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    5888kB time=00:00:57.45 bitrate= 839.6kbits/
frame= 1475 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    6144kB time=00:00:58.60 bitrate= 858.9kbits/
frame= 1504 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    6144kB time=00:00:59.75 bitrate= 842.3kbits/
frame= 1532 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    6400kB time=00:01:00.90 bitrate= 860.8kbits/
frame= 1562 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    6400kB time=00:01:02.10 bitrate= 844.3kbits/
frame= 1591 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    6656kB time=00:01:03.25 bitrate= 862.0kbits/
frame= 1617 fps= 52 q=19.0 size=    6656kB time=00:01:04.27 bitrate= 848.3kbits/
frame= 1645 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    6912kB time=00:01:05.42 bitrate= 865.4kbits/
frame= 1672 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    6912kB time=00:01:06.47 bitrate= 851.8kbits/
frame= 1701 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    7168kB time=00:01:07.62 bitrate= 868.3kbits/
frame= 1729 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    7168kB time=00:01:08.77 bitrate= 853.8kbits/
frame= 1758 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    7424kB time=00:01:09.93 bitrate= 869.7kbits/
frame= 1785 fps= 52 q=22.0 size=    7424kB time=00:01:10.99 bitrate= 856.6kbits/
frame= 1813 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    7680kB time=00:01:12.14 bitrate= 872.0kbits/
frame= 1841 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    7680kB time=00:01:13.30 bitrate= 858.3kbits/
frame= 1870 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    7936kB time=00:01:14.41 bitrate= 873.7kbits/
frame= 1898 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    7936kB time=00:01:15.54 bitrate= 860.6kbits/
frame= 1925 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    7936kB time=00:01:16.65 bitrate= 848.2kbits/
frame= 1953 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    8192kB time=00:01:17.78 bitrate= 862.8kbits/
frame= 1980 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    8192kB time=00:01:18.80 bitrate= 851.6kbits/
frame= 2008 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    8448kB time=00:01:19.91 bitrate= 866.0kbits/
frame= 2036 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    8448kB time=00:01:21.06 bitrate= 853.7kbits/
frame= 2062 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    8704kB time=00:01:22.09 bitrate= 868.6kbits/
frame= 2089 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    8704kB time=00:01:23.17 bitrate= 857.2kbits/
frame= 2117 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    8960kB time=00:01:24.30 bitrate= 870.6kbits/
frame= 2144 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    8960kB time=00:01:25.39 bitrate= 859.5kbits/
frame= 2172 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    9216kB time=00:01:26.48 bitrate= 873.0kbits/
frame= 2198 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    9216kB time=00:01:27.53 bitrate= 862.5kbits/
frame= 2225 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    9472kB time=00:01:28.61 bitrate= 875.6kbits/
frame= 2252 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    9472kB time=00:01:29.70 bitrate= 865.0kbits/
frame= 2278 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    9472kB time=00:01:30.73 bitrate= 855.2kbits/
frame= 2296 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    9728kB time=00:01:31.49 bitrate= 871.0kbits/
frame= 2324 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    9728kB time=00:01:32.58 bitrate= 860.7kbits/
frame= 2349 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    9984kB time=00:01:33.58 bitrate= 873.9kbits/
frame= 2374 fps= 53 q=22.0 size=    9984kB time=00:01:34.57 bitrate= 864.8kbits/
frame= 2400 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=   10240kB time=00:01:35.59 bitrate= 877.5kbits/
frame= 2425 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=   10240kB time=00:01:36.61 bitrate= 868.2kbits/
frame= 2450 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=   10496kB time=00:01:37.62 bitrate= 880.8kbits/
frame= 2475 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=   10496kB time=00:01:38.60 bitrate= 872.0kbits/
frame= 2501 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=   10496kB time=00:01:39.66 bitrate= 862.7kbits/
frame= 2528 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=   10752kB time=00:01:40.75 bitrate= 874.2kbits/
frame= 2553 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   10752kB time=00:01:41.73 bitrate= 865.8kbits/
frame= 2581 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=   11008kB time=00:01:42.82 bitrate= 877.0kbits/
frame= 2607 fps= 53 q=23.0 size=   11008kB time=00:01:43.89 bitrate= 868.0kbits/
frame= 2630 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   11264kB time=00:01:44.81 bitrate= 880.4kbits/
frame= 2655 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   11264kB time=00:01:45.81 bitrate= 872.1kbits/
frame= 2681 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   11264kB time=00:01:46.83 bitrate= 863.7kbits/
frame= 2707 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   11520kB time=00:01:47.88 bitrate= 874.8kbits/
frame= 2733 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   11520kB time=00:01:48.94 bitrate= 866.2kbits/
frame= 2755 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   11776kB time=00:01:49.80 bitrate= 878.6kbits/
frame= 2781 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   11776kB time=00:01:50.82 bitrate= 870.5kbits/
frame= 2807 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   12032kB time=00:01:51.89 bitrate= 880.9kbits/
frame= 2835 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   12032kB time=00:01:53.00 bitrate= 872.2kbits/
frame= 2862 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   12288kB time=00:01:54.09 bitrate= 882.3kbits/
frame= 2889 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   12288kB time=00:01:55.15 bitrate= 874.1kbits/
frame= 2916 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   12544kB time=00:01:56.30 bitrate= 883.5kbits/
frame= 2943 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   12544kB time=00:01:57.33 bitrate= 875.8kbits/
frame= 2969 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   12800kB time=00:01:58.37 bitrate= 885.8kbits/
frame= 2995 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   12800kB time=00:01:59.40 bitrate= 878.2kbits/
frame= 3023 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   13056kB time=00:02:00.53 bitrate= 887.3kbits/
frame= 3052 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   13056kB time=00:02:01.68 bitrate= 878.9kbits/
frame= 3081 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   13056kB time=00:02:02.83 bitrate= 870.7kbits/
frame= 3109 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   13312kB time=00:02:03.98 bitrate= 879.5kbits/
frame= 3133 fps= 52 q=23.0 size=   13312kB time=00:02:04.97 bitrate= 872.6kbits/
frame= 3151 fps= 52 q=-1.0 Lsize=   13918kB time=00:02:06.01 bitrate= 904.8kbits/s dup=1 drop=0 speed=2.08x    
video:7750kB audio:6073kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.688174%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] frame I:19    Avg QP:14.14  size: 10147
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] frame P:804   Avg QP:16.08  size:  4710
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] frame B:2328  Avg QP:18.47  size:  1699
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] consecutive B-frames:  1.0%  1.0%  1.5% 96.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] mb I  I16..4: 17.6% 70.4% 12.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] mb P  I16..4:  1.9%  7.2%  1.0%  P16..4: 46.6% 24.3% 10.4%  0.0%  0.0%    skip: 8.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.7%  0.1%  B16..8: 41.2%  8.8%  1.4%  direct: 4.5%  skip:43.1%  L0:45.0% L1:45.8% BI: 9.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] final ratefactor: 17.18
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] 8x8 transform intra:71.3% inter:81.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 72.7% 86.5% 67.7% inter: 22.0% 28.2% 3.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] i16 v,h,dc,p:  5%  7%  3% 85%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 17% 16%  9%  7%  8%  8%  9% 10%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 21% 13%  7% 10%  8% 10%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] i8c dc,h,v,p: 38% 20% 16% 26%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] Weighted P-Frames: Y:8.7% UV:2.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] ref P L0: 48.0%  6.0% 25.7% 19.2%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] ref B L0: 80.5% 12.4%  7.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] ref B L1: 93.1%  6.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7f81d7820400] kb/s:503.64
[aac @ 0x7f81d7000800] Qavg: 188.932
```

Comment: Nothing obvious here. Maybe it doesn't like 5.1 AAC, although it's a weak guess from a lack of anything else. Try adding `-ac 2`.

Comment: Adding `-ac 2` fixes processing a file with just trimming; when I combine it with resizing the video and h264 codec, I get the same error.

Comment: Show your new command with the complete log.

Comment: I updated the question with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that 5.1 audio channels is the problem. Add `-ac 2` to convert it to stereo:

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 1.5 -to 2:07.500 -i /Volumes/NO\ NAME/PRIVATE/AVCHD/BDMV/STREAM/00147.MTS -vcodec libx264 -vf scale=540:-1 -vb 500k -ac 2 ~/Downloads/message.mp4
```

Location of options is important. In this case `-ac 2` needed to be applied as an output option: `ffmpeg [input options] -i input [output options] output`